# Pass around state without cluttering code with implicits

Tags: scala, immutability, implicit

I have a hierarchy that looks like this:

```
trait Player
trait Player1 extends Player
trait Player2 extends Player
trait Human extends Player
trait Computer extends Player
```

I have a function literal that will map user input to an instance of type Players where `type Players = Tuple2[Player1, Player2]`:

```
val initialize: Array[String] => Players = (args: Array[String]) =>
  args.map(_.trim.toLowerCase) match {
    case Array("x") =>
      (new Player1 with Human, new Player2 with Computer)
    case Array("o") =>
      (new Player1 with Computer, new Player2 with Human)
    case _ =>
      (new Player1 with Human, new Player2 with Computer)
    }
```

Is there a way I can let my other classes know about `Players` without having to pass around Players implicitly all over? e.g.

```
def nextPlayer(player: Player)(implicit players: Players): Player =
  player match {
    case _: Player1 => players._2
    case _: Player2 => players._1
  }
```

I want to avoid side effects as much as I can so I haven't used something like:

```
object GameState {
  var player1: Player = _
  var player2: Player = _
}
```

However would this be the only way of getting around having to pass `Players` to all methods that require it?

Answer (score 1):

Embed the individual players within a `Players` class:

```
class Players(init: Array[String]) { players =>  
  trait Player
  ...
  val (p1, p2) = init.map(_.trim.toLowerCase match {
    case Array("x") => (new Player1 with Human, new Player2 with Human)
    ...
  }

  def nextPlayer(player: Player): Player = if (player eq p1) p2 else p1
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have some coupling between Players and other classes that need access to it. For example with your approach I would still have to instantiate the class and pass it around to my AI module.

Comment: @SamuelHeaney - Being explicit is often a good thing--you do want to know _which_ players you're working on if you have more than one set of players.  If you never will, you can either embed AI within players, or have players be a constructor parameter to the AI class so you can always refer to it from within AI methods.